# Need detail understanding about "Application is MultiTenant" in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image]
will setting "Application is Multitenat" make my application work with other tenants which are not registered in my azure subscription. which are not part of my active directory. will setting this option work with any ###@###.onmicrosoft.com. the image you see is from azure active directory web app page. i have register my web application to consume the office 365 api as describe in page https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context of Azure AD:

A `single tenant application` is only available to users of Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) where this is created.

A `multi tenant application` is not only available to users of Azure AD where it is created but it also available in other Azure ADs. Users in other Azure ADs have to explicitly grant consent to the application in their Azure AD. When an application is added to another Azure AD, that application essentially becomes a user in that Azure AD as a `Service Principal`.

Comment: will my application be able to access the tenant of my frnd azures subscription, if i say it as multitenant, i understand that it will be able to access the multiple tenant in same azure subscrition, what about tenant from differnt azure subscription

Comment: To answer your question, yes. Because of the way Azure AD management is presented in the Azure Portal, one is led to believe that Azure AD is part of an Azure Subscription (even I thought so too) however they are separate entities all together. I would highly recommend reading this post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/. This has certainly cleared my confusion :).

Comment: nice to see you @GauravMantri Sir. We have met at Global Azure Bootcamp. :)

Answer (score 1):

A **single tenant** application means application is hosted specific for a single client. Reasons may be specific business needs OR regulatory compliance OR they can be n numbers of real scenarios you can imagine.

In **multi tenant** application is available to group of clients. Reasons here can be common business needs, no regulatory compulsion, less cost in supporting maintenance & usage as same application is used for multiple clients.

Practical Example is below (**[Directly taken as it is from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534478.aspx)**):
[image]

One of the first architectural decisions that the team at Tailspin had to make about how the Surveys application could best support multiple subscribers was whether it should be a single-tenant or multi-tenant application. Figure 1 shows the difference between these approaches at a high-level. The single-tenant model has a separate physical instance of the application for each subscriber, while the multi-tenant model has a single physical instance of the application shared by many subscribers.

It’s important to note that the multi-tenant model still offers separate views of the application’s data to its users. In the Surveys application, Client B must not be able to see or modify Client A’s surveys or data. Tailspin, as the owner of the application, will have full access to all the data stored in the application.

For more details : refer [Hosting a Multi-Tenant Application on Windows Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534478.aspx)

Comment: hi, i have register my application to be able to access office365 apis as shown in https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant , i am aware of what multitenant application is, i just want to know significance of that option with respect to registering application in active directory